# How do I include a foreign key on a one-to-many relationship in an Entity Data Source?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, entity-relationship

I am working through this tutorial: http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/the-entity-framework-and-aspnet-%E2%80%93-getting-started-part-3

About 2/3 down the page, you will see this:

> The OrderByExpression element specifies that the result set will be ordered by course title within department name. Notice how department name is specified: Department.Name. Because the association between the Course entity and the Department entity is one-to-one, the Department navigation property contains a Department entity. (If this were a one-to-many relationship, the property would contain a collection.) To get the department name, you must specify the Name property of the Department entity.

How do I setup a collection for my one-to-many relationship? I looked around on the net and couldn't find an answer. I get the following message when I run the page:

> DataBinding: 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection`1[[QCPropertiesModel.Property, App_Code.s8yp4uy2, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' does not contain a property with the name 'DataPublished'.

This is my code:

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="PropertiesDataSource" runat="server" 
ConnectionString="name=QCPlacesEntities" 
    DefaultContainerName="QCPlacesEntities" EnableFlattening="False" 
EntitySetName="CustomerDetails"
include="Properties">
</asp:EntityDataSource>

    <asp:QueryExtender ID="SearchQueryExtender" runat="server" 
    TargetControlID="PropertiesDataSource" >
</asp:QueryExtender>
    <asp:GridView ID="SearchGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataKeyNames="CustomerID" DataSourceID="PropertiesDataSource"  AllowPaging="true">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date Published">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Properties.DatePublished") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerID" HeaderText="ID"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerLName" HeaderText="Last Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerFName" HeaderText="First Name" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You  have one to many relationship with `PropertiesModel` using `Eval("Properties.DatePublished")`  is incorrect because `Properties` is a collection of `PropertiesModel` so it doesn't have a property called `DatePublished`.

```
Properties[0].DatePublished
```

will have that property.